# declare code as side-effects free using microsoft code contracts

Tags: code-contracts

Is there a way to declare a method as side-effects free using [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) (.net 4)?

Comment: Did you look into the "Preconditions" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [[Pure]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx) attribute might be what you're looking for.  Just attach it to your method and Code Contracts will assume it doesn't involve any state changes.  Note that it doesn't actually enforce or check anything, it just tells the system to make that assumption, so it's up to you to make sure you're using it appropriately.